# Does MVCContrib support MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib

Does MVCContrib support MVC4? I am trying to use it in my project. Can any one help me with an example?

Comment: Note:  Experts seem to hate the "but it's not working" remark :)  What specifically doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

> Does MVCContrib support MVC4?

No.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation mentions support for the script and style bundling of MVC4.  Other discussions on codeplex indicate that T4MVC in MVC4 is working for people.

https://t4mvc.codeplex.com/documentation

> Support for MVC's script and style bundles
>
> Starting from MVC4, one can define "bundles" of scripts and
>   stylesheets which are automatically combined and minified. However,
>   magic strings are used to define the resource URLs. To eliminate them,
>   follow steps 1 to 3 below.

It appears full support for this is still being added.  But the features that worked in MVC2 I know still worked in MVC3 because I used them in MVC3; but the documentation does not explicitly say it works with MVC3.  I suspect that every feature in MVC4 that was part of MVC3 still works in MVC4.

Here is the reference discussion for bundling:
http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/discussions/399205

T4MVC is still better than relying on magic strings to reference controller actions and view names.  In my opinion the next version of MVC just needs to include T4MVC in the base feature set.  Until that happens I'll continue to use T4MVC.